Creating a custom menu in Scribus using PyQt5, when we execute script in Scribus it gives ImportError: No module names PyQt5.QtWidgets
PyQt5 is showing installed properly in Windows Command Prompt, but in scribus it says No module found.
Someone who has experience using PyQt5 in scribus please help
import scribus
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
def create_button_with_icon():
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# Create a QWidget window
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Scribus Extension")

# Load your icon (adjust the path to your icon file)
icon_path = "C:/Users/pc point/Downloads/save_file.png"
button = QPushButton()
button.setIcon(QIcon(icon_path))
button.setIconSize(QSize(64, 64))  # Adjust the size of the icon as needed

# Connect the button click event to a function
button.clicked.connect(your_button_function)

# Set up the layout
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(button)
window.setLayout(layout)

# Show the window
window.show()

# Start the PyQt5 event loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())


I suppose you're talking about this. The documentation is sparse and somehow outdated (many docs in the wiki refer to Python 2), but it seems that it uses it's own Python interpreter, not the system one, meaning that you have to install PyQt there. Note that it's also unknown the context in which the interpreter is run, and trying to run a further Qt application may lead to issues.

Thanks for the reply
Do you have any idea on how to Install PyQt5 in scribus python interpreter?

I've never heard about it until I read your post. I suggest you to check their support forum.

Ok. Thanks. Have posted on their forum, but no luck yet

You have to issues here: How to use a specific binary of Python with Scribus and how to add items to the menu.
Probably following the hints you got above, you asked the part about using a custom Python also in the Scribus forums and I answered it there (the issue being that Scribus uses its own libpython on Windows: https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Windows_Full_Python_Integration)
The part where you want to add items to the navigation is a different concern.
I'm pretty sure that I gave it a try a few years ago and I had to give up.
If I recall correctly, the main issue were:

Scribus dynamically manages the menu through a set of internal functions and does not really like it if you inject items with Qt or PyQt
I worked on giving access to those function from the scripter (in that case you would not need PyQt to add items to the menu) but Scribus relies on the menus being defined at startup: the advantage of these new functions would have been limited.

What I did a bit more lately: add a menu entry for the user's own scripts:
https://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=15579
It's a first version that simply adds all scripts from a given set of paths to the Scripter menu.
I plan to improve it to allow sub menus after (if ever) the patch gets accepted.
It's not the same as you plan to do, but, combined with the "action search", it can offer you a good enough result.
